# How to generate unique numbers inside a UDF (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, random, user-defined-functions

Is there a way to generate unique numbers (int for instance) inside a user defined function?

rand() and newid() do not work due to side-effecting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627408.aspx) gets around the NEWID() limitation

```
SELECT CHECKSUM(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8000))
```

So you can use it like this. No "side effecting" error

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.test ()
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
   RETURN CHECKSUM(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8000))
END
GO
SELECT dbo.test()
```

Comment: Thanks @gbn, this seems to be working. A little question though, CHECKSUM is not guaranteed to produce always different results for different arguments but I guess the chances to enter such a case are really small?

Comment: 1 in 4 billion (int range) uniqueness, subject to [birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). NEWID() would have the same problem because you need to get a number from the GUID.

Comment: I still get the error with an inline function: Msg 443, Level 16, State 1, Procedure //InlineFunctionName//, Line //LineNum// [Batch Start Line 0]
Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'Crypt_Gen_Random' within a function.

Comment: I had the same problem as Riley. Surrounding the function with the CHECKSUM doesn't prevent the error.

Answer (score 1):

In DB2 I use the microsecond portion of the timestamp but SQL server only goes to milliseconds. I suspect that wouldn't be good enough?

Comment: FYI, SQL Server 2008+ goes to 100ns with new types

Answer (score 1):

You also could define a view using the function that causes the side-effect (in this case RAND())

```
CREATE VIEW randomView
AS
SELECT RAND() randomResult
GO
```

Then use the view in your UDF

```
DECLARE @random DECIMAL(18,18) 
SELECT @random = randomResult FROM randomView
RETURN @random
```

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant. It is so simple that I was skeptical it would work (especially after trying for years to get around many of Microsoft's stringent & artificial limitations on functions & stored procedures) but it did the trick for me in SQL Server 2014, unlike the marked answer.